# Get Squid3 to cache .zip, .rar, .iso files for 2 weeks

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid, cache, transparent-proxy

Is there away to get Squid3 to cache certain file extensions for an extended period of time?  For example, I'd like to have .zip, .rar, and .iso files cached for 2 weeks by default.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this line into your squid.conf and reload the config.

```
refresh_pattern .*\.(zip|rar|iso) 2880  0% 2880 override-expire
```